# Cannot instal APK or OBB onto phone. Unreal Engine 4

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, game-development

I am just trying to get a test app set up and packaged to my phone with Unreal Engine 4. It is just an empty starter level because I wanted to make sure that I had the Android CodeWorks set up correctly and that I could package a game and get it to work on a phone. Everything was running smoothly until it came time to actually install the APK and OBB files onto my phone. Below is a log that I am getting and to the best of my knowledge nothing is wrong.

```
E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>setlocal

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>if NOT "" == "" (call \HostWin64\Android\SetupEnvironmentVars.bat )

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>set ANDROIDHOME=E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>if "E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows" == "" set ANDROIDHOME=E:/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>set ADB=E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>set DEVICE=

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>if not "" == "" set DEVICE=-s

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>for /F "delims=" %A in ('E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell "echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE"') do @set STORAGE=%A

Uninstalling existing application. Failures here can almost always be ignored.

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe  uninstall com.E10Studios.TwinStickShooter

Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.E10Studios.TwinStickShooter
        at com.android.server.pm.Settings.getInstallerPackageNameLPr(Settings.java:4671)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstallerPackageName(PackageManagerService.java:25411)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:25417)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:21125)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:924)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1486)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:25953)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3329)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4763)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)

Installing existing application. Failures here indicate a problem with the device (connection or storage permissions) and are fatal.

E:\My Games\FirstGame\TwinStickShooter\Android_ATC>E:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe  install TwinStickShooter-arm64-es2.apk
Failed to install TwinStickShooter-arm64-es2.apk:
There was an error installing the game or the obb file. Look above for more info.

Things to try:
Check that the device (and only the device) is listed with "ADB$ devices" from a command prompt.
Make sure all Developer options look normal on the device
Check that the device has an SD card.
```

I have checked to make sure that my device shows up with the "ADB devices" command and I am pretty sure that all my dev options are good to go because I only need the USB debugging active right? As for the SD card, there is one and it has plenty of space, and so does my internal storage as well.

I am just really confused and would appreciate any help that anyone could give. I appreciate your time and thank you very much in advance. Also, I am really new to this so I apologize if the solution to the problem is something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I was just messing around with the settings on my phone and fixed the issue. For anyone else who might be having the same problem, with your phone connected to your PC and USB debugging turned on, drag down to bring up the menu, click on android system notification and change your USB transfer setting from file transfer to image transfer. It worked right away for me.

Comment: It is not like that, changing the transfer type will detect your phone. some times mobile will disconnect or undetected by the studio or computer. that time simply change the transfer type or plugin your phone once more.